# Retrieve values from firebase database in conversation flow

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

I am trying to grab information from my firebase database after a particular intent is invoked in my conversation flow.
I am trying to make a function which takes a parameter of user ID, which will then get the highscore for that user, and then say that users highscore back to them.

```
app.intent('get-highscore', (conv) => {
  var thisUsersHighestscore = fetchHighscoreByUserId(conv.user.id);

  conv.ask('your highest score is ${thisUsersHighestScore}, say continue to keep playing.');

});



function fetchHighscoreByUserId(userId){
  var highscoresRef = database.ref("highscores");
  var thisUsersHighscore;

  highscoresRef.on('value',function(snap){

    var allHighscores= snap.val();
    thisUsersHighscore = allHighscores.users.userId.highscore;

  });
  return thisUsersHighscore;

}
```

An example of the data in the database:

```
 "highscores" : {
    "users" : {
      "1539261356999999924819020" : {
        "highscore" : 2,
        "nickname" : "default"
      },
      "15393362381293223232222738" : {
        "highscore" : 78,
        "nickname" : "quiz master"
      },
      "15393365724084067696560" : {
        "highscore" : "32",
        "nickname" : "cutie pie"
      },
      "45343453535534534353" : {
        "highscore" : 1,
        "nickname" : "friendly man"
      }
    }
  }
```

It seems like it is never setting any value to `thisUsersHighScore in` my function.

Comment: "allHighscores.users.userId.highscore;" doesn't reflect the JSON object at the bottom of your code snippet. Am I right ?

Comment: i think it does, the userId is the value i pass in the function. maybe i got my syntax wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues going on here - both with how you're using Firebase, how you're using Actions on Google, and how you're using Javascript. Some of these issues are just that you could be doing things better and more efficiently, while others are causing actual problems.

**Accessing values in a structure in JavaScript**

The first problem is that `allHighscores.users.userId.highscore` means "In an object named 'allHighscores', get the property named 'users', from the result of that, get the property named 'userId'".  But there is no property named "userId" - there are just a bunch of properties named after a number.

You probably wanted something more like `allHighscores.users[userId].highscore`, which means "In an object named 'allHighscores', get the property named 'users', fromt he result of that, get the property named by the value of 'userId'".

But if this has thousands or hundreds of thousands of records, this will take up a lot of memory. And will take a lot of time to fetch from Firebase. Wouldn't it be better if you just fetched that one record directly from Firebase?

**Two Firebase Issues**

From above, you should probably just be fetching one record from Firebase, rather than the whole table and then searching for the one record you want. In firebase, this means you get a reference to the path of the data you want, and then request the value.

To specify the path you want, you might do something like

```
var userRef = database.ref("highscores/users").child(userId);
var userScoreRef = userRef.child( "highscore" );
```

(You can, of course, put these in one statement. I broke them up like this for clarity.)

Once you have the reference, however, you want to read the data that is at that reference.  You have two issues here.

1. You're using the `on()` method, which fetches the value once, but then also sets up a callback to be called every time the score updates. You probably don't need the latter, so you can use the `once()` method to get the value once.
2. You have a callback function setup to get the value (which is good, since this is an async operation, and this is the traditional way to handle async operations in Javascript), but you're returning a value *outside* of that callback. So you're always returning an empty value.

These suggest that you need to make `fetchHighScoreByUserId()` an asynchronous function as well, and the way we have to do this now is to return a Promise. This Promise will then resolve to an actual value when the async function completes. Fortunately, the Firebase library can return a Promise, and we can get its value as part of the `.then()` clause in the response, so we can simplify things a lot. (I strongly suggest you read up on Promises in Javascript and how to use them.) It might look something like this:

```
return userScoreRef.once("value")
  .then( function(scoreSnapshot){
    var score = scoreSnapshot.val();
    return score;
  } );
```

**Async functions and Actions on Google**

In the Intent Handler, you have a similar problem as above. The call to `fetchHighScoreByUserId()` is async, so it doesn't finish running (or returning a value) by the time you call `conv.ask()` or return from the function. AoG needs to know to wait for an async call to finish. How can it do that? Promises again!

AoG Intent Handlers *must* return a Promise if there is an asyc call involved.

Since the modified `fetchHighScoreByUserId()` returns a Promise, we will leverage that. We'll also set our response in the `.then()` part of the Promise chain. It might look something like this:

```
app.intent('get-highscore', (conv) => {
  return fetchHighscoreByUserId(conv.user.id)
    .then( function(highScore){
      conv.ask(`Your highest score is ${highScore}. Do you want to play again?`);
    } );
});
```

Two asides here:

1. You need to use backticks "`" to define the string if you're trying to use ${highScore} like that.
2. The phrase "Say continue if you want to play again." is a very poor Voice User Interface. Better is directly asking if they want to play again.